# CouchDB in iOS / Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, couchdb, couchbase-lite

Is there a simple solution or framework to use a couchDB database in an iOS application? I need to copy a database and store it locally in the app, so I need functions like pulling down a remote database, etc. What would be the best route for me to take to access my couchDB in my app (in swift)? I have tried couch base lite, but have had much trouble using it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are few options :

- [CouchBase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios)
- [CouchCocao](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchCocoa/)
- [TouchDB-IOS](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS)

According to my search, CouchBase Lite seems the best options.

You can also develop your own library. Since CouchDB has a HTTP RestFul API, it's pretty easy to do.

Otherwise, [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) if a very powerful library to use CouchDB on mobile. Therefore, it's only available for hybrids applications(JavaScript).

Comment: All three that you listed on top were created by the same developer, and only Couchbase Lite is maintained. The others have not been touched in years so they are not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked over 3 years ago, and just wanted to update the list.

You might want to also take a look at this

https://github.com/cloudant/swift-cloudant

`A Swift Lang client for Cloudant and CouchDB`

I haven't tried it yet, but plan to as I am also still looking for a way to use CouchDB on an iOS project of mine.

Comment: This is simply a wrapper to interact with a CouchDB or Cloudant database's http API, not a full local database with sync replication. There appears to be (as of 2020) nothing like PouchDB for native mobile that will sync with CouchDB (Couchbase lite no longer uses the same sync protocol).

Comment: you are completely right, unfortunately I also have looked for a native Swift CounchDB local database in vain.... and thought that maybe swift-cloudant might be of use, even though it looks like it hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Yes unfortunate, as of now the way I see it if you want offline-first, collaborative database (without writing your own sync engine) you're looking at two options. Realm (the service) is not open source but the database itself is. It has now been aquired by mongodb and offers a generous free tier for the sync service, the only other option is Couchbase lite and running and managing a Couchbase instance serverside.